# Azure Table Storage - How to keep initial order of columns after update or merge?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Table Storage to write senor data to the Table Storage using the Insert Entity Command of the REST API. When I watch the tables using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, the Columns appear in the order I initially used to store them in the table with the Insert Entity command. When I edit an Entity with e.g. the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and then watch the table again, the columns (properties) are sorted alphabetically according to the property names from left to right.
I’m now trying to write a Xamarin.Forms application where I want to keep the initial order of the columns after  updating (editing) an entity. Is there a library or method I can use to update an entity without destroying the initial order of columns?

Answer (score 2):

@Zhaoxing Lu Thanks for your answer.
Yes, it seems that Table Storage Service is not intended to support a special order of columns. If an entity is inserted using `WindowsAzure.Storage library`, the properties are returned alphabetically.

However I use a more "handmade" method to store data in Table Storage on NETMF devices based on the Insert Entity method of `Table Service REST API` with an Atom Feed to hold the entity.

If the storing to Cloud is done in this way, the order of the properties in the Atom Feed is preserved and they come sorted in this order when watched with Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

As I didn’t find a way to preserve this order trying some merge or update commands of the different libraries, I now - for editing a property - go the way of :

1. get an actual copy of the Entity from the Cloud
2. delete the Entity in the Cloud
3. write the edited Entity back to the Cloud using the Insert Entity method of the Table Service REST API.

So the initial order is preserved. I know that there is a slight risk to lose the entity when the internet connection is interrupted.
For the App I’m just writing, I don’t want that my App destroys an existing order that a user eventually wants to be maintained.

Your second statement, namely that Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer by default displays the "other" columns alphabetically seem to be not absolutely correct. If they are stored in the way as described above, they are by default displayed in this order.

See my Table screenshot below:
[image: screenshot].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an order for columns in Azure Table Storage, please don't rely on it. Azure Table Storage Service doesn't care the sequence of your property names defined in code at all.

Note that Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer just returns **Partition Key + RowKey + Timestamp + other columns alphabetically**.